# Like post model with this Author already exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What i want to do is basically user can like an article once. But this error keeps me from liking another article. Here is my code:

```
class LikePostModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='postlikes',null=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='postlikes_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And here is my error:

```
Like post model with this Author already exists
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked `author` as *unique*. This means that each author can only have (at most) *one* `LikePostModel`, which is probably *not* what you want. You probably want to make it unique *per author per article*. You do this with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint):

```
from django.conf import settings

class LikePostModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # not unique=True
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='postlikes'
    )
    # not unique=True
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='postlikes_set'
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        # make the combination unique
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['author', 'article'], name='unique_like')
        ]
```

Comment: It works.Thanks a lot,but do we really need `name='unique_like'` ?

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: You just need to specify a name for the constraint, that can be any valid identifier.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!